# Writing a single column from a table in MS Access VBA to .txt file

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

this is my first time posting a question here, but I almost always get good answers from searching this site. I'm trying to find out if there is a better way to speed up this process I have of writing a table column in Access to a .txt file. Here is the code I have, which works, but it's on the slow side. It takes about 45s to write around 7000 items.

```
lsFileName2 = "E:\DOI_Inventory2\SyncData\EquipUser.txt"
LiFileNumb = FreeFile

SysCmd acSysCmdSetStatus, "Updating User Equipment List"

Open lsFileName2 For Output As LiFileNumb
    With rst
        Do While Not .EOF
            Write #LiFileNumb, ![EqUserFile]
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

dbs.Close
Close LiFileNumb
```

I'm fairly new to the IT field so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Just to add a note, the actual query is fine. I already checked that and it's pretty fast.

Comment: As Hans says, your code looks ok and shouldn't be causing any real slowness, is the E drive on a shared network, Lan or Wan etc?  If so you could try writing to the local drive and then moving the file on completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a query, save it with a name, and then use [TransferText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958.aspx) to export the query's data to your text file.

So assuming you have a `SELECT` query named *qryExportMe* like this which returns your table's column data correctly ...

```sql
SELECT EqUserFile
FROM YourTable;
```

... refer to this `TransferText` example and adapt it to fit your needs.

```vb
DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acExportDelim, _
    Tablename:="qryExportMe", _
    FileName:="E:\DOI_Inventory2\SyncData\EquipUser.txt", _
    HasFieldNames:=True
```

Check the `TransferText` options at that linked page or from Access' built in help system.

Note you are not required to include the option names.  I added them to help you keep track of which is which.

If this approach speeds up your export operation adequately, I think it will be because Access handles the task as a single set-based file write.  Your recordset approach required Access to process one row at a time ... and one reason such approaches are called RBAR (row by agonizing row) is because they are often painfully slow.

Comment: Also 45 seconds to write a 7k line text file seems excessive to me, even with the RBAR approach.  So there may be something else going on that we haven't accounted for.